# Selecting sub items in CSS

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have the following HTML:

```
<div class='main'>
  <div id='image-div'></div>
  <div class='item-div'></div>
  <div class='item-div'></div>
</div>
```

The divs inside the **main** div are create dynamically via JS. So in order to change some styles with JS after they are created I created another class "main-light" and using jquery's *addClass* & *removeClass*, I'm able to change the designs of these inner divs.
This also let me do 1 addClass in the main div and change a lot of css inside the page.

This is the CSS code for the new class:

```
.main-light div#image-div, .main-light div.item-div {some css code}
```

***Question:*
Can we write the css selector more elegantly without having ".main-light" before each item?**

The above example is short, but my actual css file has many of these elements and selectors and it's getting pretty big.

Hope I made myself clear and someone can help me.

Thanks

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: No you can't do this with CSS, look into SASS then you can nest selectors (which are then transformed into normal css, as you already have)

Comment: Link: [SASS: Syntactically Awesome Style Sheets - Guide](https://sass-lang.com/guide)

Comment: I guess you could do `#image-div, .main-light .item-div {}`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `nth-child` selector in css. Checkout the following example:

```
.main > div:nth-child(1) {},
.main > div:nth-child(2) {},
.main > div:nth-child(3) {}
```